# How can I add background image (png image format) to a div with pseudoelement ::before

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I have tried puting the path of my image directly into content. then, using background and oher several properties too but dont get to make them appear yet.

this is my HTML:

```
<div class="side-links-container">
   <div class="side-link search">
     <a href="#"></a>
   </div>
   <div class="side-link questions">
      <a href="#"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="side-link contact">
      <a href="#"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

my CSS: (I use .scss)

```
    .side-link {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 4.5rem;
  height: 4.5rem;
  background: #249987;


  &.search a {

    &::before {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      display: block;
      background: url('../dist/res/img/Lupe-side-menu.png') no-repeat;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what are youa ctually trying to achieve. I bet that there are better ways to achieve what you every try to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't immediately see a problem  - the only possibility I think is that you have the wrong path to your background image OR you are seeing just a small part of your background (as the element has width and height 4.5em).

I translated the SCSS to CSS just in case there is a problem with the SCSS, but there doesn't appear to be. Here is a working snippet with a full-path background image url. Try putting a full path URL for your image in there and see what happens. Then try making it relative again. The background size is also set to cover so we get to see a reasonable amount of the image.

```css
.side-link {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 4.5rem;
  height: 4.5rem;
  background: #249987;
}

.side-link.search a::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1016/1024/768) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="side-links-container">
  <div class="side-link search">
    <a href="#"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="side-link questions">
    <a href="#"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="side-link contact">
    <a href="#"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```